# How i can get name of current route?

Tags: angular

How i can get name of current route? Not URL part, but route name or alias.

I want to do redirect inside `CanActivate` hook. If this hook return `false`, while i stayed on root route `('/')`, i need to reload page, because standart `Route.navigate` on same URL did not reload page.

Also i looked for similar questions on StackOverflow, but did not find any solution. All few solution based on Location url parsing, but this not what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**beta.x router and RC.1 router-deprecated**

I guess this is what you are looking for https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular/commit/c1d499d567d88baa10fa964459feb15b267e8c8b. Currently this seems to be only available using the private `_currentInstruction` field of the `Router`.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5335#issuecomment-170088933

> in the meantime, if you want the current route instruction, you can subscribe to the router for URL updates and convert that into an instruction.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, Instruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouterState {
  _current: Instruction;

  constructor(public router: Router, location: Location) {
    // subscribe to router url updates
    router.subscribe((url) => {
      // convert the current url into an instruction
      this._getInstruction(url);
    });
  }

  private _getInstruction(url) {
    this.router.recognize(url).then((ins) => {
      if (ins) {
        // Store the current route instruction
        this._current = ins;
      }
    });
  }

  current() {
    // return current instruction
    return this._current;
  }
}
```